# Trying to get this Excel VBA Timestamp code to work on two different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I'm very new to excel, essentially i am trying to get this Timestamp to work on two separate excel sheets to record what times staff are entering values into the main sheet.

I have created a module with :

```
Function MyTimestamp(Reference As Range)

If Reference.Value <> "" Then

MyTimestamp = Format(Now, "ddmm hhmm")

Else

MyTimestamp = ""

End If

End Function
```

It works well for the sheet i am using but i would also like this to work with another sheet in the same Excel Spreadsheet, Is there any line that i could that that would direct to a specific sheet of my choice?

Very confusing to me but would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you share an example of how you are using it at the moment and a short description, maybe even pseudocode, of how you would like to use it with another worksheet?

Comment: I assume you want to use this function as UDF (User Defined Function) in Excel? You need to put the code into a regular module, not in the worksheet code, else it is not known in other sheets.

Comment: Instead of using a UDF, it'd likely be better to use the `Workbook.SheetChange` event and hard-code the timestamp.